# Check a string to see if it is "^M"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I tried `(char-equal chars ^M)` , but failed. I always get error. How can I compare these special characters?

Update: the solution is `(string-equal chars (char-to-string ?\^M))`

Update2: the solution is `(string-equal chars "\^M")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. `(string-equal chars "\^M")`.

@Chang Peng @Sean Thanks any way. :-)

Comment: `(char-to-string ?\^M)` is more compactly written as `"\^M"`.

Comment: @user4815162342 "\^M" is string... It will cause error in "char-to-string"

Comment: The idea is to not call `char-to-string` at all, since you have a string to begin with. As my comment says, replace `(char-to-string ?\^M)` with `"\^M"`.

Answer (score 1):

Control-M is written in Emacs Lisp as `?\C-m`.  See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Ctl_002dChar-Syntax.html#Ctl_002dChar-Syntax) for more details.

Comment: I can replace the second variable `^M` with `?\^M` or `?\^M`. But the compare function still fail when the first variable is `^M`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you entered "^M" in your function as "^" followed by "M". But that's 2 characters. In emacs the correct way to input the ^M character is C-q C-m, and "^M" will show on your screen in a slightly different color.